# how to call all functions in jquery using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made many functions like $.redux.select and I want call all functions when dialog_finished event is trigger

here are the codes in field_select.js file

```
(function($){
    "use strict";

    $.redux = $.redux || {};

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.redux.select();
    });

    $.redux.select = function(){
        //some code here
    }   

})(jQuery);
```

here are the codes in redux.js file

```
(function($){
    "use strict";

    $.redux = $.redux || {};

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var the_body = $(document);
        the_body.on('dialog_finished', function(event, window){
            //render all methods
            $.each($.redux, function( method, value ) {
                /*******************************************************************/
                   my problem is below , how to call $.redux.select() using $.each
                   or there is better way
                /*******************************************************************/
                $.redux.$method();
            });
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each($.redux, function( name, value ) {
    value();  // call the function
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EAgfP/

or

```
$.each($.redux, function( name, value ) {
    $.redux[name]();  // call the function
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EAgfP/1/